# How to run hybrid app AngularJS/Material1 with Angular/Material2

Tags: css, angularjs, angular, angular-material, angularjs-material

i currently have an AngularJS + angular materialv1 app, and we're migrating it to Angular + angular materialv2.
We're running it in hybrid mode for now. All is working well except for the CSS styles.

Styles from material 1 and 2 are conflicting. 
I read that i need to use the "compatibility mode" : https://github.com/angular/material2/pull/2790

But I couldn't find out how to set it. Would anyone know how to turn it on ?

Thanks for your help on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution [here](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/src/lib/core/compatibility/compatibility.spec.ts): i need to import the NoConflictStyleCompatibilityMode class along with MaterialModule

```
import { MaterialModule, NoConflictStyleCompatibilityMode  } from '@angular/material';
...
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        MaterialModule,
        NoConflictStyleCompatibilityMode
    ],...
```

If that can help someone...

Comment: You may accept (mark it with a green check mark) your own answer to allow future visitors to faster identify your solution.